# Call function after update auth_user

Tags: django, authentication, legacy

I have a question about how could I update a legacy table after an update in the auth_user table.

I would like to do some changes in other tables just after the "admin" changes the data of one of the users.

Is there a way to call a function when the auth_user's table is modificated?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoy can use  post_save signals. It is exactly what you are looking for.
Lear more on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/signals/

Comment: The problem is that I need to get the signal from the admin form panel when the admin updates an auth_user. I have no different view.

Comment: When admin updates some record in auth_user model, post_save signal will be send. You can write your callback function to process it.